# 0-1 knapsack problem with minimum and maximum weight capacity

Tags: knapsack-problems

In classical [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition) we have maximum allowed value for the weight - weight capacity.

Let's restrict total knapsack weight by min and max values

$$
M \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_i x_i} \leq W
$$

Is there any known algorithm for this problem?
Is there anything known which is better than brute force?

I failed to find anything about the given knapsack problem variation.

Answer (score 3):

We can change the definition of the traditional Knapsack to "the maximum value we can get from the first `n` items using exactly `W` weight" instead of "the maximum value we can get from the first `n` using at most `W` weight". The easiest way to do this by replacing the following code:

```
for j from 0 to W do:
    m[0, j] := 0
```

from the Wikipedia article dynamic program pseudo code with

```
m[0, 0] := 0
```

Then we simply need to check for the maximum value of the range `m[n, M]` , ... , `m[n, W]`.

Comment: thank you for the idea. I have changed the DP algorithm from Wikipedia to make it work in my case. You helped me greatly in doing this.